# Export Video from powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, video, export, powerpoint

I want to export a video from powerpoint using VBA. This video was uploaded from the PC and not using links. I saw that this is possible for the images using this line of code:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Export "C:\Cover.PNG", ppShapeFormatPNG
```

but I couldn't do the same for videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply need to extract the original video from the PPTX file?  If so, rename the file to give it a .ZIP extension, open the zip file, browse for the media folder and in it, you'll find copies of any inserted (but not linked) sounds, videos and pictures.

If you have routines for working with ZIP files in VBA, you could probably work out how to do the same thing.

A possible alternative:  size the video to fill the slide, then use PPT's SaveAs method to save as a WMV.